# How to configure the y axis to reduce zeros and save space?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

Looking for the suitable matplotlib or searborn configuration to raise to power and save space. The visualization I prefer is marked in red color.

[image]

Comment: check the docs: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0, 4))
```